# Product custom variant property for "Buy with PayPal" button?

Tags: shopify, liquid

We can add a custom variant property to any product by adding hidden input(s) in the add to cart form on product pages in main-product.liquid (Dawn theme):

```
<form method="post" action="/cart/add" id="product-form-template--17081662406963__main" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate" data-type="add-to-cart-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="product">
    <input type="hidden" name="utf8" value="✓">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="44030441193779">
    <input type="hidden" name="properties[Size]" id="custom-size" value="5T">
    <input type="hidden" name="properties[Color]" id="custom-color" value="Blush Pink">
</form>
```

It works well with the **Add to cart** and **Buy it now** buttons that the custom properties **Size** and **Color** are successfully relayed to checkout and eventually to order information.

You can try it here: https://www.meblush.com/products/off-shoulder-corset-black-lace-tulle-court-mermaid-wedding-dress

This product has NO variants defined at all but we are able to select custom options (Size, Color) for it for checkout.

However, this doesn't seem to work for the **Buy with PayPal** button and the custom properties are **NOT** transferred to the popup PayPal checkout window.

If you try this product with REAL native variants: https://www.meblush.com/products/princess-ivory-lace-blush-pink-tulle-flower-girl-dress

And click the **Buy with PayPal** button, the popup PayPal checkout window does have the product name appended with the variant selected, e.g. "- 2T / Blush Pink".

But with our custom property hidden input Size and Color, the PayPal checkout window isn't notified of the custom properties in the form we added.

My question is, how can we make it work for the "**Buy with PayPal**" button as well?

I looked through the HTML and there doesn't seem to have any variable to feed the custom properties to PayPal?